# how to pass javascript object with getter/setter into angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `setting` object with setter/getter for a calculated field `setting.addressbits`.

```
 $scope.setting = {
    address:'111111',
    get addressbits() {
       return this.address.split('').map(Number);
    },
    set addressbits(val){
        this.address = val.join('');
    }
};
```

That is passed into a 2-way binding custom directive. It seems `getter` of the object returns a fresh object every time, which angular doesn't like [as explained](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig)

```
 .directive("bitField", function(){
   return {
      scope:{
      bits: "="
   },
 template: '<div>custom directive</div>'
 }
  });



<bit-field bits="setting.addressbits"><</bit-field>
```

[live code here](https://jsfiddle.net/99h2pgwo/5/)

How shall I do it right?

Comment: why can't you use service, to set the object and then inject that service in the directive and then use the getter.